# Create a back link using (IFrame) that counts as a dofollow back-link

Tags: html, iframe, seo

I am wanting to create a short passage of HTML which includes a back link to our domain (Domain A) and counts as a do follow back link. I am going to use a IFrame to display this on other domains so that when i update the passage it will update on the multiple domains. However i have a concern:

- As the HTML that I'm displaying through a IFrame is hosted on Domain A but displayed on Domain B, will it still give a backlink to Domain A from Domain B, or will it just be a internal link from Domain A to Domain A.

Example Below:

```html
<iframe src="http://w14media.com/wp-content/uploads/2016/03/arsenalbadge-1.html" width="200" height="200" frameborder="0">
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do actual test with iframe like that. After google has crawled and indexed your iframed page at `Domain B`, check your Google Webmaster Tools of `Domain A` for link, if google will consider it as backlink then this link will appear in `Search Traffic` > `Links to your site`. Otherwise it should be under `Internal Links` (from `Domain A` to `Domain A`). Look at these articles:

https://www.merkleinc.com/blog/iframe-test-do-search-engines-follow-links-iframes
https://www.seroundtable.com/google-iframe-link-14558.html